# Swift UILocalNotification Display On Screen

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I am trying to display a `UILocalNotification` on the top of the screen when it is received. I have created a simple notification

```
var notification = UILocalNotification()
notification.alertBody = "Hello World!"
notification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0)
UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
```

This displays like it should in the Notifications section when the user swipes down on the screen, but is there a way to also show a notification on the top of the screen to alert the user when the app is running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement this in your appdelegate and show an alert :

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification) {

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was hoping the local notification had a function to display a notification on the top of the screen, but it appears I will have to create my own view for that.

Comment: May be, create a new UIWindow and display it as level alert ?